# How to start Firefox multiple isolated sessions with same profile?

Tags: firefox, profile, proxychains

I use `proxychains` utility with firefox. I want to start the firefox profile twice, but with other `proxychains` parameters. But I can't, when I try to run the second instance of firefox with the same profile, it's just opens a new window of exiting session.
I have tried this commands: `firefox -P profile %u`, `firefox -P profile --new-instance`, `firefox -P profile --no-remote`, `firefox -P profile --new-window`. Nothing worked.
Hope for your help!

Comment: You cannot. Firefox will not start another instance with the same profile.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to have separate cookie sessions? If so checkout the multi-account container. It is an add-on

1. Go to Firefox menu -> Add-ons.
2. Search for "Firefox Multi-Account Containers"
3. Add to Firefox

It looks like below.

[image]

Link: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/

Comment: Thanks, but no. I want to run firefox profile with different proxies using proxychains linux utility. It means that I need to run new firefox process, but not only new window.